# Enter commit message when saving Azure Data Factory to Git

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to change the commit message when saving an Azure Data Factory to git?

Whenever you press save it seems you get a commit and that commit will change say Updating *pipeline name*. While sort of useful it would be nice to actually put in some descriptions of what's changed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure Data Factory does not currently support to customize the commit message. We can upvote the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34570885-add-ability-to-customize-the-commit-message-when-s) to let Microsoft improve this feature.

Comment: The link is broken now. Any updates on that as of 2022. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft just enabled this capability. The announcement has no details, but this is what you do to turn it on:
Go to the "Manage" section of Azure Data Factory, click "Git configuration", then "Edit":
[image: Azure Data Factory Git Configuration]

Now check the "Use custom comment" checkbox:
[image: Edit Git Repository Configuration]

(I also recommend setting up CI/CD and therefore checking the "Disable publish" checkbox as well. That checkbox is only available when you're in the default branch.)

Now when you save, an area slides out from the right of the screen allowing you to edit a commit message. If you use Azure DevOps, if your message contains "#" followed by a valid workitem ID, the commit is linked to the workitem, just like with other Git tooling.

Caveats:

1. This is not a "require comments" checkbox. Upon save, a "standard comment" is supplied. The developer may delete it entirely. (Boo, MSFT.)